# Creating a data.frame Column with paste statement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Current dataFrame like:

```
BaseTable
S.no.  Category    First  Second  Third
1      Abc Class    10     12      3
2      Xyz Class    12      3      4
3      asd Class    10      2      4
```

Now ,I want to add a column in this data frame using paste statement in data.frame. I have tried doing it with `assign()` and `noquotes()` but r create a new variable with that name.

```
First = unique(BaseTable$First)
Count = 1    
Combinations = c('First', 'Second', 'Third')
For(i in combinations){
   assign(paste("BaseTable$no", Count, "[BaseTable$", i ," %in% ", i[j], "]", sep = ''), j)
   Count = Count +1
}
```

The Output I am getting is a variable name `BaseTable$no10[BaseTable$Perfect %in% Perfect]`
Secondly, here `i` is a vector which has multiple elements, but with paste statement, it show the `i[j]` values as NA.
Like for `First[1] = NA`.

I want And output like:

> ```
> BaseTable
> S.no.  Category    First  Second  Third  No1   No2   No3
> 1      Abc Class    10     12      3      1     1     1
> 2      Xyz Class    12      3      4      2     2     2
> 3      asd Class    10      2      4      1     3     2
> ```

Comment: Please try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: Could you illustrate how the desired `data.frame` should look?

Comment: @Karan ? [duplicates] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-an-index-from-a-variable-in-a-dataframe

Comment: @Karan, you should avoid the Capital letter.. and test your code before you post it the this one fo not work: `For` instead of `for`, `Combinations` instead of `combinations`.

Comment: This is a sample code,in the real code there is no such problem, but from the next time i will be carefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was here [How to create an index from a variable in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-an-index-from-a-variable-in-a-dataframe)

```
BaseTable$No1 <- as.numeric(factor(BaseTable$First))
BaseTable$No2 <- as.numeric(factor(BaseTable$Second))
BaseTable$No3 <- as.numeric(factor(BaseTable$Third))
```

for the loop:

```
combinations = c('First', 'Second', 'Third')
count = 1

for (i in combinations) {

  BaseTable[[paste("No", Count, sep="")]] <- match(BaseTable[[i]], unique(BaseTable[[i]])) # same order
  #BaseTable[[paste("No", Count, sep="")]] <- as.numeric(factor(BaseTable[[i]])) # new order
  count = count +1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I am still curious to know how to create dataframe columns with paste as i don't need to specify

Comment: BaseTable$No1 n BaseTable$No2. as i would be able to do this in a loop