# How to index column uniquely in Python using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to generate a unique index column in my dataset.

I have a column in my dataset as follows:
665678, 665678, 665678, 665682, 665682, 665682, 665690, 665690

And I would like to generate a separately indexed column looking like this:
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3

I came across the post [How to index columns uniquely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975784/how-to-index-columns-uniquely)? that describes exactly what I am trying to do. But since the solutions are described for R, I wanted to know how can I implement the same in Python using Pandas.

Thanks

Comment: Use `df.columns = pd.factorize(df.columns)[0] + 1`

Comment: Or use `df.col1.astype('category').cat.codes + 1`

Comment: Thank you guys. Both the solutions work and having read the [Pandas DENSE RANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357882/pandas-dense-rank), `factorize` seems to be the right option considering that my data is sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df.groupby('col').ngroup()+1
```

**Output**

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey @Vivek, thanks for the help