# How to assign a custom unique id to different elements in a column?

Tags: r

I have a column named quadrant in my dataset:

```
Quadrant
NW
NE
SW
NE
```

I want to create a new column named `Quad_id` containing custom ids for each direction like:

```
Quadrant      Quad_id
NW            10001 
NE            10002
SW            10003
NE            10002
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a consecutive index based on a grouping variable in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-index-based-on-a-grouping-variable-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Sorry for the typo @markus.

Comment: Edited my question with the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- You can use `match`:

  ```
  transform(dat, id = match(Quadrant, Quadrant) + 10000)
  #   Quadrant    id
  # 1       NW 10001
  # 2       NE 10002
  # 3       SW 10003
  # 4       NE 10002
  ```

  where `dat` is the name of the data frame.
- You can also use `as.factor`:

  ```
  transform(dat, id = as.integer(as.factor(Quadrant)) + 10000)
  #   Quadrant    id
  # 1       NW 10002
  # 2       NE 10001
  # 3       SW 10003
  # 4       NE 10001
  ```