# Create Group from Sequences

Tags: r

How can I create a "group" vector that identifies sequences of same values in another vector.

From this

```
x <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
```

I want to create this

```
outcome <- c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6)

[1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

So, whenever there is a new sequence of the same values there is a new group number (or can be something other than a number as well).

---

I would actually know ways to get there, but they are all hideous. The best I can come up with is

```
comparison <- x != lag(x)
cumsum(replace_na(comparison, TRUE))
```

but like I said - hideous. There must be a better way and I hope someone knows it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*How to create a consecutive index based on a grouping variable in a dataframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6112803/2204410)

Comment: @Jaap I do not get it. Why do you close the question? The "duplicate" you linked does **not** answer this question here. Please, read more carefully before you close a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rleid(x)
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or in `base R` with `rle`

```
with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or if we use the similar approach from OP

```
1 + cumsum(x != dplyr::lag(x, default = first(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is always only 0s and 1s, another option is

```
cumsum(c(1, (x[-1] + head(x, -1)) %% 2))

[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

a `tidyverse` version that does a condition, replaces the `NA` and sums cumulatively:

```
library(tidyverse)

if_else(outcome == lag(outcome), 0, 1) %>% 
  replace_na(1) %>% 
  cumsum()

[1] 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```