# How to mark the number of each rows with a group by

Tags: r

I have a certainly stupid question, but here is how looks my data:

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
D
D
D
D
```

All I want to do is that :

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
D 1
D 2
D 3
D 4
```

I guess it should be with a group by function and an easy line in R, but I don't find words to find the good topic.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-index-based-on-a-grouping-variable-in-a-dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
data$numbers <- group_indices(data, letters)
```

Data:

```
data <-data.frame(letters= c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"))
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.