# Create class column in data.table given a numeric vector

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Currently I have a data.table like this:

```
item    dummyvar  
4q7C0o     1         
2BrKY63    1         
3drUy6I    1         
G5ALtO    1000        
G5G859    1000
PAP589    2000
```

And using a defined function I find out that the rows where there is a significant change in the `dummyvar` are in a numeric vector called `imbalance = 4 6`. What I would like to do is to create a new column in my data table such that all the rows below the given numbers given by `imbalance` are in a given class, for ex. something like this:

```
item    dummyvar   Class
4q7C0o     1         1
2BrKY63    1         1
3drUy6I    1         1
G5ALtO    1000       2 
G5G859    1000       2
PAP589    2000       3
```

Comment: Okay, I gave an answer an realised that I did not understand your `imbalance`-part. Could you be more precise? I just numerated the groups, but don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps `your_data_table[, Class := cumsum(.I %in% imbalance)]`? I'm assuming `imbalance` is a vector of the row numbers where you want `Class` to increment. (This version starts at  0, but you could stick a `+ 1` on it to start at `1`)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [*How to create a consecutive index based on a grouping variable in a dataframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6112803/2204410)

Comment: @MartinGal, `imbalance` is a numeric vector where each number tells the row where the class should change, for ex. rows 1-3 should be class 1, and then rows 4-5 will be class 2

Comment: @Oliver Ah, I see. I removed my answer for being off-topic.

Comment: @MartinGal on the contrary, thank you for your time for commenting and checking my problem. I appreciate it

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you, That is what I was looking for. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `your_data_table[, Class := cumsum(.I %in% imbalance)]`? I'm assuming imbalance is a vector of the row numbers where you want Class to increment. (This version starts at 0, but you could stick a + 1 on it to start at 1)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the vector `imbalance` contains the row indices into the data.table at which a new `Class` should start.

Here is one possible solution (among many other, I suppose) using `cut()` on the row index `.I`:

```
dt[, Class := cut(.I, c(0, imbalance, Inf), labels = FALSE, right = FALSE)][]
```

> ```
>       item dummyvar Class
> 1:  4q7C0o        1     1
> 2: 2BrKY63        1     1
> 3: 3drUy6I        1     1
> 4:  G5ALtO     1000     2
> 5:  G5G859     1000     2
> 6:  PAP589     2000     3
> ```