# Assign a conditional value to new created column

Tags: r

My Data frame looks like this

[image]

Now, I want to add a new column which assigns one (!) specific value to each country. That means, there is only one value for Australia, one for Canada etc. for every year.

It should look like this:

```
Year Country   R  Ineq Adv   NEW_COL
2018 Australia R1 Ineq1 1    x_Australia
2019 Australia R2 Ineq2 1    x_Australia
1972 Canada    R1 Ineq1 1    x_Canada
...
```

Is there a smart way to do this?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `paste(Year, Country, sep = "_")`?

Comment: Does this help [How to create a consecutive group number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-group-number) ?

Comment: I guess I need several if conditions that check the country name and then assign one value to each country (constant over the years).

Comment: Could you make your desired output clearer? `x_Australia` isn't super helpful, unless you literally want `paste("x", Country, sep = "_")`. What is `x`? Is it okay if it is the year? That would seem clear and useful. Or do you want it to be a number starting with 1? If two countries have the same year, should `x` be the same for them? Or do you want  x = 1 for each country's first year? Or something else?

Comment: Or do you just want a single number, `1` is Australia 2018, `2` is Australia 2019, `3` is Canada 1972, ...? If it's this, do you care about the order? Do you want consecutive values for the same country, increasing by year?

Comment: And the wording in your question is confusing: *"one (!) specific value to each country"* make me think, well, one value per country. But your next sentence, *"one value for Australia, one for Canada etc. for every year"* makes me think one value per country per year. And do you want the vales to be integers? Or are string values okay?

Comment: If what you're after is one integer ID for each country, then `df$NEW_COL = as.integer(factor(df$Country))` is a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

you use `merge`.

```
x = data.frame(country = c("AUS","CAN","AUS","USA"),
           val1 = c(1:4))
y = data.frame(country = c("AUS","CAN","USA"),
               val2 = c("a","b","c"))
    merge(x,y)
    

      country val1 val2
1     AUS    1    a
2     AUS    3    a
3     CAN    2    b
4     USA    4    c
```

You just manually create the (probably significantly smaller!) reference table that then gets duplicated in the original table in the merge. As you can see, my 3 row table (with a,b,c) is correctly duplicated up to the original (4 row) table such that every AUS gets "a".

Answer (score 0):

You may use `mutate` and `case_when` from the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(country = rep(c("AUS", "CAN"), each = 2))

data <- mutate(data,
               newcol = case_when(
               country == "CAN" ~ 1,
               country == "AUS" ~ 2))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate` and `group_indices`:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Sample data:

```
   sample.df <- data.frame(Year = sample(1971:2019, 10, replace = T),
                           Country = sample(c("AUS", "Can", "UK", "US"), 10, replace = T))
```

Create new variable called `ID`, and assign unique ID to each `Country` group:

```
sample.df <- sample.df %>%
  mutate(ID = group_indices(., Country))
```

If you want it to appear as `x_Country`, you can use paste (as commented):

```
sample.df <- sample.df %>%
  mutate(ID = paste(group_indices(., Country), Country, sep = "_"))
```