# Recode a numeric variable with many values including NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, forcats

How to recode a numeric variable with many values including missing values, to have numbers `0:n-1` where `n` is the number of unique values including `NA`, in a tidy way?

Example:

```r
df <- tibble(x = c(1000, 1000, NA, 1001, 1002, 1003, NA, 1003))
```

Required output (though it can be any recoding scheme as long as the values are `0:n-1`):

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  1000     0
2  1000     0
3    NA     4
4  1001     1
5  1002     2
6  1003     3
7    NA     4
8  1003     3
```

I *am* able to do this in a tidy way by first converting `x` to a factor then using `fct_recode()` with a named list (created automatically because remember there are *many* values in `x`), then back to numeric:

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(x_fct = factor(case_when(
    is.na(x) ~ "level_na",
    TRUE ~ str_c("level_", x)
  )))
x_levels <- levels(df$x_fct)
n_levels <- length(x_levels)
names(x_levels) <- as.character(0:(n_levels - 1))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(y = as.numeric(fct_recode(x_fct, !!!x_levels)) - 1)
df
```

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 3
      x x_fct          y
  <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1  1000 level_1000     0
2  1000 level_1000     0
3    NA level_na       4
4  1001 level_1001     1
5  1002 level_1002     2
6  1003 level_1003     3
7    NA level_na       4
8  1003 level_1003     3
```

But this seems very cumbersome. Surely there's a simpler way, preferably in a single pipe.

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(x, exclude = NULL)) - 1`. Somewhat related: [How to create a consecutive group number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-group-number)

Comment: A polite way to say duplicate, thanks @Henrik.

Comment: But they don't explicitly consider `NA` - the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `match` + `unique`. You can add `sample` to add randomness

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(level = paste('level', x, sep = '_'), 
         y = match(x, sample(unique(x))) - 1)

#      x level          y
#  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#1  1000 level_1000     4
#2  1000 level_1000     4
#3    NA level_NA       2
#4  1001 level_1001     0
#5  1002 level_1002     1
#6  1003 level_1003     3
#7    NA level_NA       2
#8  1003 level_1003     3
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I'd change it to `df %>% mutate(y = match(x, unique(x)) - 1)` since the `level` variable in my code is just a helper and no randomness is required.

Comment: Comparing with `microbenchmark` on `x` the length of 100K, @Ronak's answer is about x10 faster on my machine: `df <- tibble(x = sample.int(1000:10000, size = 100000, replace = TRUE)); 
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  match(df$x, unique(df$x)) - 1,
  as.numeric(factor(df$x, exclude = NULL)) - 1
)`