# nth group labelling (count only graduates with new group)

Tags: r, data.table, partition-by

Say, I have a `df`:

```
df <- data.table(user = c('a', 'a', 'b')
                 ); df

user
 a
 a
 b
```

I am looking to create a new column, `group_id`, at `user` level:

```
user group_id
 a        1
 a        1
 b        2
```

Is there a fast / scalable way? I can do this with a join (and understand `data.table` is fast with joins) but wonder if there is a simpler and faster method.
Assume I have circa 1e8 rows and the method is to be applied to multiple columns in the group by (in example presented there is only 1 i.e. `user`)

I have started with:

```
df[, step_1 := as.integer(duplicated(df))]; df

user step_1
 a      0
 a      1
 b      0
```

but don't know what is next nor am I sure if this is even the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may also use `match`

```
df[, group_id := match(user, unique(user))]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I too benchmarked this and took 0.91 sec on 1e7 rows
Who would have thought a ase R solution would be this quick

Answer (score 2):

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)’s special symbol `.GRP` will also work with multiple grouping columns

```
df[, group_id := .GRP, by = user][]
```

> ```
> user group_id
>    a        1
>    a        1
>    b        2
> ```

Alternatively, the `rleid()` function can be used but this requires that the dataset is ordered by the very same columns:

```
df[order(user), group_id := rleid(user)][]
```

> ```
>    user group_id
> 1:    a        1
> 2:    a        1
> 3:    b        2
> ```

Comment: Thank you. However, `rowid` does not give the result as presented. it would give group_id = c(1,2,1) because it does an intra group row count
Am I mistaken?

Comment: @SweepyDodo Yes, you are right, `rowid()` was the wrong function. I had meant the `.GRP` special symbol.

Comment: Not a problem. Still appreciate your reply!
A fellow stacker redirected me to a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-group-number/69617625#69617625) where I have provided some benchmarking if you are interested
p.s. yes, rleid is tricky as one has to order first

Answer (score 1):

Convert user to factor.  Then convert that to integer to extract the underlying codes that factor uses.

```
df[, group_id := as.integer(factor(user))]
df
##    user group_id
## 1:    a        1
## 2:    a        1
## 3:    b        2
```

Comment: Grothendireck
Thank you for your prompt reply. Yours does work. However, what if there are multiple columns to be grouped by?

Comment: paste them together `group_id  := as.integer(factor(paste(user, user2)))`

Comment: Thank you. Silly of me to not have thought of pasting.
I'm benchmarking possible solutions atm. Will comment again later

Comment: I have just behcnmarked this method. While it works and is read-able it does not scale well with large data. Still, it was good to learn as I had rarely used `factor` before. Thank you!
p.s. took 5.27 secs on 1e7 rows

Comment: Some kind soul linked me to an older thread where I have now provided a benchmark result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-group-number/69617625#69617625)