# Creating a counter that increments along changes in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am working with data structured somewhat like the following:

```
testdat <- data.frame(MyDat = c("a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b"))
```

I would like to create a counter variable `MyCount` that iterates along `MyDat`, breaking and adding 1 to the count whenever there is a shift in the factor level of 'MyDat. Ideally, the result would look something like this:

| MyCount | MyDat |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | b |

I am struggling with trying to figure out how to set this loop up for checking whether one row value is equivalent to the previous row and if not then breaking and adding one to the counter. It also appears I need to start iterating only on the second row onward. Something like:

```
testdat <- data.frame(MyDat = c("a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b"))

v <- vector(mode = "integer", length = length(testdat))
counter <- 1
for(i in v) {
  if(testdat[, MyDat] == testdat[i-1, MyDat]) {
    counter
  } else {
    counter = counter + 1
}

both <- cbind(v, testdat)
```

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112803/how-to-create-a-consecutive-group-number/74129105#74129105) for a complete set of answers

Comment: @Maël while there are answers there that would address this question, they are not exactly the same questions. However, I guess that's why you didn't use your Mjolnir. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `consecutive_id`

```
library(dplyr)
testdat %>%
  mutate(MyCount = consecutive_id(MyDat), .before = 1)
```

-output

```
    MyCount MyDat
1        1     a
2        1     a
3        2     b
4        2     b
5        2     b
6        3     a
7        3     a
8        3     a
9        3     a
10       4     b
```

---

Or in `base R` with `rle`

```
with(rle(testdat$MyDat), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
 [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Two `base` options:

```r
# (1)
cumsum(c(1, tail(testdat$MyDat, -1) != head(testdat$MyDat, -1)))

# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```

```r
# (2)
cumsum(c(1, diff(as.integer(factor(testdat$MyDat))) != 0))

# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `data.table::rleid` does:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(testdat)[ , MyCount := rleid(MyDat)]
```

```
#>     MyDat MyCount
#>  1:     a       1
#>  2:     a       1
#>  3:     b       2
#>  4:     b       2
#>  5:     b       2
#>  6:     a       3
#>  7:     a       3
#>  8:     a       3
#>  9:     a       3
#> 10:     b       4
```